# How should I go about caching a large table in pySpark?

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark

I have defined the following function:

```
def hdfsToSchemaRDD(hdfsPath, tableName, tableHeader):
    lines = sc.textFile(hdfsPath)
    fields = [StructField(field_name, StringType(), True) for field_name in tableHeader.split()]
    schema = StructType(fields)
    columns = lines.map(lambda l: l.split(","))
    tempTable = columns.map(lambda c: tuple([ c[i] for i,v in enumerate(tableHeader.split()) ]))
    schemaTable = sqlContext.applySchema(tempTable, schema)
    schemaTable.registerTempTable(tableName)
    sqlContext.cacheTable(tableName)
```

The intention being to read a dataset from a hdfs, given the path, and store it into memory so that I don't have to read it anew every time I need to query it, which is often.

The issue I am having is that suppose I load some large table `LargeTable` and run the function:

```
def FeatureSummary(features):
    results = sqlContext.sql("""
        SELECT
            %s
            ,SUM(summable) as s1, SUM(othersummable) as s2
        FROM
            LargeTable
        GROUP BY
            %s
        ORDER BY
            %s
    """%(features,features,features))
    for row in results.map(lambda x: x).collect():
        print row
```

`FeatureSummary(attribute1)`, `FeatureSummary(attribute2)`, `FeatureSummary(attribute3)` seem to read in `LargeTable` every single time.  In particular, I would expect, given that the attributes have very few levels, that the query in the `FeatureSummary` function would run much faster the the reading in of `LargeTable`.  This is NOT the case.

Is there a way to check whether or not a table has been cached?
How can I modify the function `hdfsToSchemaRDD` to actually cache the data from the hdfs?